# Request multithreading with array

Tags: multithreading, perl, http, request

This script reads a file of urls to do multithreading HTTP requests.

How can I use an array with urls to make multithreading requests?

My array will have something like:

```
@array = ("https://example.com/xsd","https://example.com/xys","https://example.com/des","https://example.com/hduei");
```

I need to remove the function of reading file with urls, but I can not.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

use Fcntl              qw( LOCK_EX );
use IO::Handle         qw( );
use LWP::UserAgent     qw( );
use Thread::Queue 3.01 qw( );

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 20;

my $output_lock :shared;
my $output_fh;
sub write_to_output_file {
   lock($output_lock);
   print($output_fh @_);
   $output_fh->flush();
}

sub worker {
   my ($ua, $url) = @_;
   my $response = $ua->get($url);
   write_to_output_file("$url\n")
      if $response->success
      && $response->content =~ /Exist/;       
}

{
   $output_fh = \*STDOUT;  # Or open a file.

   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
   for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
      async {
         my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( timeout => 15 );
         while (my $job = $q->dequeue()) {
            worker($ua, $job);
         }
      };
   }

   while (<>) {
      chomp;
      $q->enqueue($_);
   }

   $q->end();
   $_->join() for threads->list();
}
```

Comment: Replace the `while` loop with `$q->enqueue($_) for @my_array_of_urls` ?

Comment: Scalar found where operator expected at inicia.pl line 195, near "@array
   $q"
        (Missing operator before $q?)
syntax error at script.pl line 195, near "@array

   $q"
Execution of inicia.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: I wouldn't use LWP::UserAgent. I'd use Net::Curl::Multi. Way faster, and don't have to deal with threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the code you've shown reads filenames from the command line arguments, and then reads all the lines in these files. It then iterates over the lines.

```perl
   while (<>) { # <--- here
      chomp;
      $q->enqueue($_);
   }
```

You can replace that with an array, which of course needs a `for` loop. Make sure to remove the `chomp`, as there won't be a need to remove newlines.

```perl
   foreach (@urls) {
      $q->enqueue($_);
   }
```